# Selenium throws error when swapping Iframe, Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to switch to another frame but Selenium always throws an error:

Code:

```
ca_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="s1i518j4-2 bLslTo"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(ca_frame)
```

Gives me the following error

> WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing
>   'value'   (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.32.498550
>   (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)

which I have never seen before. The thing is that it returns an element using xpath.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stack trace ,

> Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.32.498550

Your chrome driver is very old, which is incompatible with this Chrome version. If you head over to the chromedriver [website](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), you can see that the you should use `ChromeDriver 2.39` which `Supports Chrome v66-68` or `ChromeDriver 2.40` which `Supports Chrome v66-68`.

Please update the chromedriver and then try again. If the xpath is correct, it should be able to jump to the frame.